# writing xmlwriter contents to a linq to sql xelement field

Tags: xelement, xmlwriter

I have a field in a table defined as xml so in my dbml it's showing up as an xelement.  I have an xmlwriter in my class that needs to write it's xml to this field but calling tostring on the writer doesn't work.  How do I assign the xmlwriter or it's contents to an xelement? Thanks.